# .info() not displaying null values

Tags: python, pandas, null

I have a dataframe and using df.info() I get the following output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 371899 entries, 0 to 8933
Data columns (total 2 columns):
col_a    371899 non-null object
col_b    371899 non-null object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 8.5+ MB
```

So it seems like there are no null values, but typing:

```
pd.isnull(df['col_b']).sum()
```

I get 74. Why are these null values not detected with .info() ?

Another thing that I don't understand is why .info() reports object, which should be used for strings, but the values in col_b are float actually...

Answer (score 0):

Probably, for some reason, the Pandas Dataframe is being imported with the columns being interpreted as Objects, and, as objects the null values are not null. Try to specify the columns as Floats with

```
df['col_b'] = df['col_b'].astype(float)
```